# Shared Mailbox in Microsoft graph in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to look for a way to identify shared mailbox and/or convert a regular mailbox to shared in C#.

From what I tried to look for I found nothing using `GraphServiceClient`.

I'm referring to getting a user with:

> `var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();`

or

> `var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Select("MailboxSettings").GetAsync();`

and identifying if the user has a regular mailbox or shared.

**Note:** Not talking about shared folders

is there a way using `Microsoft.Graph` or any other way to identify and/or convert mailbox in asp?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're asking, but there's documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-share-messages-folders

Comment: @Nikki9696 Hi, i updated the question to explain what i meant

Comment: I see - it looks like they have a userPurpose attribute in beta but not yet in 1.0. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/userpurpose?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: @Nikki9696 interesting, bummer that it's still in beta. wanted to avoid using it, but I guess EWS not supported anymore and features going to graph something will be missing. thanks  for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

As this feature is still available only in the Beta endpoint and not in V1.0, You can raise a feature for same and upvote it so that it can be moved to the V1.0 endpoint.

Feature Request:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform.

Hope this helps.